# Is there any way to convert or copy .msg (outlook) file contents into .txt file in Python 2.7.5 on Unix machine?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find a way where I can either read the .msg outlook contents in Python 2.7.5 so that I can copy them in a text file for further processing.

How can I parse outlook file in python (2.7.5) code ?

Below is the code :

```
import sys
from io import open

open('/usr/tsp/TRIAL/input.msg') as f:
 print f.read()
.
.
.
.
Error :
File "test1.py", line 10
    open('/usr/tsp/TRIAL/input.msg') as f:
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: 1) Python 2.7 is end of life, so best you upgrade 2) Yes, Python can parse email files. https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer : The thing is, upgradation is not getting accepted on that unix machine as there are multiple python scripts currently present and running they are not allowing me to upgrade just for this issue. So anyway, I need to find a solution where I can read .msg outlook mail in python 2.7. Even copying all of the contents to text file would also help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could use pyenv / Pipenv to install user-local versions of Python, and slowly upgrade your codebase. The unix server shouldn't matter. Any external library you find will likely have already dropped support for Python2, just as pip has. Have you tried using the linked library? What issues are you having with it? It's also [part of Python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.parser.html). Or, the answer to your question is simply `open('file.msg') as f: print f.read()`. Don't need to copy anything since msg are already "text files"

Comment: @OneCricketeer : No,I don't have permissions to upgrade anything on that machine. ".msg" file is not a text file.It's an outlook file which contains mail subject,other details & body.Code isn't reading contents same as text file.It's printing this data :<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/usr/tsp/TRIAL/input.msg' encoding='UTF-8'> (which is not correct).Tried the way you mentioned above but getting:"SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Tried to resolve this error by putting "with" before "open" & now getting this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: pyenv / pipenv doesn't need "sudo permissions". Both can be installed in user-space. Please [edit] your question with code you've tried and errors you are getting; the `Community` is a bot, that is asking you to do the same

Comment: You could process the files on a different machine. You could then re-implement the same algorithm on that legacy machine. Those are all issues of your work infrastructure, not programming questions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : Can we parse .msg outlook mail files in python 2.7.5 ?

Comment: Yes. It might require some effort on your side, but it's not a problem per se.